# Navigating between asp.net mvc pages and passing data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating an asp.mvc 4 application. I have scenario where I have an MVC page which is bound to a model. Within the same page, I have a grid to add "areas".

Now I need the option to create the "Area": which is when the user clicks on a button ("btncreatearea"), another page will open which will have "area" details and on submission it will be redirected back to the original page.

I also want the information entered on the original page as it is before the user clicks to add area from another page.

I tried to call another page by using the script below but this does not work properly - it never opens up the page and also I am not getting any values in Model.

**Pack View**

```
@model iSPYCMS.Models.iSPYPack

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div style="text-align:right; padding-top:10px">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "Packs", null, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = 100 })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Description)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Description, new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = 250 })
    </div>

    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <strong>Add/Remove Area From this Pack</strong> Changes will takes place when save button is pressed!
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <button id="btnaddArea" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Add Area</button>
            <button id="btncreatearea">Create Area</button>
            <hr/>
            <table id="grdareas" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive table-condensed table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>OrderIndex</th>
                    <th>Area Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>ImageId</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Script**

```
  $("#btncreatearea").click(function () {

        var pack =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))        

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ pack: pack }),
            url: '@Url.Action("CreateFromPack", "Area")',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (result) {


            }
        });            
    });
```

Comment: You making an ajax call. Ajax calls do not redirect to another page (the whole point is to stay on the same page). And `var pack =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))` is the original model, so its a bit pointless posting that back to the controller

Comment: Yes i can understand ajax call will not work in this case. what could be the possible solution then?

Comment: Its not even clear from the code you have shown what your trying to do - I cant even see a button with `id="btncreatearea"` All you have shown is a whole lot of irrelevant HtmlHelpers in a view which don't appear to have anything to do with your question

Comment: I think the issue is with your use of "page".  The usual solution to this problem is to have your grid, an 'add button' opens a "modal window" using ajax to generate a form, "save" on the form doesn't post back but updates the grid, then save saves the entire grid.  When you talk about "opening a page" it implies navigating to a whole new page, which won't give you what you want without some quite nasty session caching or passing back-forth huge amounts of data.  Ofc, depends on the size of the "form" in the modal as it might need to be a whole page.

Comment: @freedomn-m i think you are right. i will need modal forms here.